# React компоненты

Tags: reactjs

В папке components можно вкладывать папку одного компонентам в папку другого?

Например, есть header, в нем 4 компонента. Я могу сделать в папке components 1 папку Header и в ней будет и код самого Header и еще 4 папки внутренних компонентов.

Или же вкладывание таким образом нежелательно и в components в этом примере должно быть 5 папок на одном уровне. Или может нет правил на этот счет вовсе?

Comment: делайте как удобно. излишние вложения как по мне ухудшают читабельность дерева файлов/папок в IDE

Comment: Папка "компоненты" создаётся же вами.  Просто делайте так, что бы вам было удобно и вы не запутались где что лежит. Реакт это потом все равно в свою кашу превратит)